# Trouble with API responses

Tags: rest, shopify, zapier, discogs-api

This is slightly niche since it focuses on the [Discogs API](https://www.discogs.com/developers#page:marketplace,header:marketplace-listing-post), but I'm hoping someone on this more active forum might have experience with it.

I'm working on a data engineering problem to try and reduce inventory lag. my goal is to pull my inventory here into Shopify, and then when something sells in store, pull it from discogs.

Things I've got working:

1. pulling my inventory into airtable
2. Zapier then creates new 'products' in my Shopify.
3. Shopify can pull sold items from sales tickets

In theory that should only leave
4. simple POST to marketplace listings to mark as draft or DELETE to remove it.

4 has proven anything but simple.

I've done the oauth flow for my app, and have keys (hence the ability to pull inventory into Airtable), but running

```
POST https://api.discogs.com/marketplace/listings/11111111?status=Draft&key=key&secret=secret
```

gets

> You are not allowed to view this resource. Please authenticate as the owner to view this content.

What gives? Similar failings with

```
DELETE https://api.discogs.com/marketplace/listings/11111111?key=key&secret=secret
```

What am I doing wrong? Also looking if anyone has tips on using Zapier's web hooks to do the removals.

Comment: possibly more confusing: when running items via the python discogs app in the next comment, I can modify items without trouble.

Comment: https://python3-discogs-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#user-token-authentication

Comment: this is hard to answer, you could check this resouce https://www.discogs.com/forum/thread/796381, try to clean up cache and data of the app. (very bottom of the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Discogs but your problem seems to be related to some sort of failure while authenticating with Discogs (I assume the problem isn't specific to the marketplace/listings endpoint, rather with any discogs endpoint, correct?)

You mentioned doing the oauth flow for your app, yet in your example you're showing the usage of a key & secret combo. This seems related to the [Discogs auth flow](https://www.discogs.com/developers#page:authentication,header:authentication-discogs-auth-flow) which is a different flow.

Citing the Discogs docs,

> BUT using the key and secret does not identify the requester as any
> particular user, and as such will not grant access to any resources
> users should be able to see on their own account (e.g. marketplace
> orders, private inventory fields, private collections). You will need
> to use either of the token options for these resources.

If possible, try to generate a token as suggested by the documentation and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: this ended up being fairly close; it seems it needed an authorization in a different spot prior to working. I thought having the key was enough but you also had to sort of fingerprint the key.